# SWT Progress Bar

Tags: java, progress-bar, swt, jface

I have a jface Dialog which has some text fields and a SWT progress bar. Once this dialog box opens the progress bar starts updating but it is somehow blocking the GUI and I am unable to enter values in the textbox. How can I make progress bar independent of other views on the GUI ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPJlf.png)

I have tried to add  background Job

```
private BackgroundJob backgroundJob = new BackgroundJob("Executing Background Task");
backgroundJob.schedule();

private class BackgroundJob extends UIJob {

    public BackgroundJob(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setSelection(0);

                methodToBeExecuted()

                stopProgressBar();

            }
        });

        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
}
```

Comment: google "daemon thread"

Comment: Display.asyncExec still runs the code in the UI thread. WizardDialog / Wizard / WizardPage can provide a proper progress monitor. Or can use org.eclipse.jface.wizard.ProgressMonitorPart